# JavaScript function doesn't work with 'onload'

Tags: javascript

I have a function I cannot modify in my script. Before start this function I need to get some data from the other script, then depends on this data - start or not to start the function.

```
var new_script = document.createElement('script');
new_script.type = "text/javascript";
new_script.src = "http://someurl.com/somedata/";
document.body.insertBefore(new_script, document.body.firstChild);

var my_blackbox_function_depends_on_data = function(){
    // Code I cannot change...
}

new_script.onload = function () { if (some_data_from_script) {
    my_blackbox_function_depends_on_data();
}};
```

But when I start this, `my_blackbox_function_depends_on_data();` - doesn't work.

`onDomReady` doesn't work too.

Is there any other way to start this function depends on data from the script? Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `some_data_from_script ` when you `console.log` it?

Comment: Then your problem is most likely that `some_data_from_script` is a falsey value and therefore `my_blackbox_function_depends_on_data` does not get executed.